# code not executing after for loop -- javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function that is supposed to loop through all my checkboxes and load the "value" of the checkboxes that are checked into an array, however nothing is executing beyond the first for loop.  I'm completely stumped here, what am I missing?

```
function saveSettings(){
    var count = 1; //count for db
    var checked=[]; //array of checked values
    var inc = 0; //only incremented when checkbox is checked
    var dataString = "x";

    for(var i=0; i<=2; i++) { //loads checked array with checked values
        if(document.getElementById("check"+i).checked == true){
            checked[inc] = document.getElementById("check"+i).value;
            alert(checked[inc]) // <------ executing as expected
            inc++;
        }
    }

    alert("made it") // <------ not executing
    if(checked.length>0){ // loads checked values into dataString
        for(var i=0; i == checked.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                dataString = "co_" + count +"="+checked[i]
            }
            else {
                dataString = dataString +"&co_" + count +"="+checked[i]
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    alert(dataString)
```

Comment: how many checkboxes are there... any error in your browser console

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle ?

Comment: Or at least post your html code

Comment: One issue to be aware of is scoping. You are using var i=0 TWICE. 'i' already exists by the time it makes it to the second loop.

Comment: @livepo but the scopes are different. If he was using i =0; without the 'var' declaration, there would be a problem.

Comment: make your first loop condition :   i<2

Comment: Also, instead of using alert, you should use console.log. Browsers will block multiple alerts after a certain number.

Comment: @batman, why the i<=2 in the for? Could you provide your HTML too?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/531kjvd8/2/ - looks fine

Comment: The second for loop should be `for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {`

Comment: @lockedz you should use 'let' instead of 'var' in that case. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword

Comment: it works fine though, check the fiddle.

Comment: Do you have 3 checkboxes with id `check0`, `check1` and `check2` or just 2

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/531kjvd8/3/

Comment: @livepo oh, that makes sense. Thanks, mate.

Comment: I checked the fiddle @ArunPJohny created. Looks like it's working there.  I tried testing on chrome and ie and it is still not getting past that for loop? There are currently only 2 checkboxes but that number is dynamic could be 2 could be 100. I plan to replace the 2 with something like "checkbox.length" variable.  Just put the 2 for testing purposes.

Comment: @livepo `let` is a bit too new… it requires this weird version opt-in to JavaScript 1.7 or above in Firefox… I wouldn’t recommend it now.

Comment: This question is answerable by debugging the code with [debugging tools](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) available in your browser. Watch out for _errors_. [Rubber Duck Debug](http://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. If you are not sure what your code does, use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger). Make sure your code is _valid_ with tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com). Only _then_, ask a question on StackOverflow and _show your research_.

Comment: can you add a common class to all the checkboxex

Comment: or do you want to consider all the checkboxes in the page

Comment: @batman see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/531kjvd8/5/

Comment: @Xufox I think modern browsers allow it if you 'use strict'; Also, I found this question under nodejs. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added a common class to all the checkboxes, your last fiddle help immensely, and it is all working now thanks!

Comment: @batman I've added it as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of the problem, I think the problem is the number of checkboxes, if you have only 2 checkboxes then the condition `i<=2` will cause problem because `docuement.getElementById('check2')` will be undefined causing an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null` in your console.

Since you are trying to deal with dynamic number of elements try to use a class to select the checkboxs of interest like

```js
function saveSettings() {

  var checked = [];
  var dataString = "x";

  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
  //if you can't add a class then fetch all the checkboxes in the page
  //var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked == true) {
      checked.push(checks[i].value);
    }
  }
  console.log("made it: ", checked)

  if (checked.length > 0) {
    dataString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
      dataString += (i == 0 ? '' : '&') + "co_" + i + "=" + checked[i]
    }
  }
  alert(dataString)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check0" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check1" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check2" value="3" />
<br />
<button onclick="saveSettings()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line

`if(document.getElementById("check"+i).checked == true){
//...`

the getElementById will return an **undefined** value, and undefined does not have the .checked property.

how many checkboxes do you have in the document?

Answer (score 0):

Try below working solution. Second for loop condition in your code (i == checked.length) is wrong. It should be `i < checked.length)`

```
function saveSettings() {

        var count = 1; //count for db
        var checked = []; //array of checked values
        var inc = 0; //only incremented when checkbox is checked
        var dataString = "x";

        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) { //loads checked array with checked values
            if (document.getElementById("check" + i).checked == true) {
                checked[inc] = document.getElementById("check" + i).value;
                inc++;
            }
        }
        if (checked.length > 0) { // loads checked values into dataString
            for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    dataString = "co_" + count + "=" + checked[i]
                }
                else {
                    dataString = dataString + "&co_" + count + "=" + checked[i]
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        alert(dataString)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your second for loop had a mistake

```js
function saveSettings(){
    var count = 1; //count for db
    var checked=[]; //array of checked values
    var inc = 0; //only incremented when checkbox is checked
    var dataString = "x";

    for(var i=0; i<=2; i++) { //loads checked array with checked values
        if(document.getElementById("check"+i).checked == true){
            checked[inc] = document.getElementById("check"+i).value;
            alert(checked[inc]) // <------ executing as expected
            inc++;
        }
    }

    alert("made it") // <------ not executing
    if(checked.length>0){ // loads checked values into dataString
        for(var i=0; i < checked.length; i++){
            if(i === 0){
                dataString = "co_" + count +"="+checked[i]
            }
            else {
                dataString = dataString +"&co_" + count +"="+checked[i]
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    alert(dataString)
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check0"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2"/>
<button onclick="saveSettings()">Run</button>
```